# Redirect to custom error page instead of default liferay error page

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, custom-error-pages

I want to redirect user to own error page instead of default liferay error page.I am using 6.1.1 CE ga2.

I tried

```
layout.show.http.status=true
layout.friendly.url.error=/error
```

inside portal-ext but no luck.

Comment: Useful link: http://www.shashantpanwar.com/2013/07/how-to-overridehide-liferay-default.html

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't specified for which type of error's you need to display custom error pages so i am showing it for 500.You can implement for others.

Add following configuration in the application server web.xml.

$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml

```
<error-page>
         <error-code>500</error-code>
         <location>/ErrorPages/Error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Make changes for redirection in the error pages.

> < script>location.href='/web/ip/login';< / script >

you can also achieve it through ext plugin . I never tried it. i will try and let u know

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1

Show Error Page:-

**Step 1**:-  Go to portal servers

```
liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT\html
```

Create new folder with name “error”

**Step 2** :- Paste attached image (`accessDenied.png`) in new created path

```
 liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT\html\error
```

**Step 3** Change in

```
portal-ext.properties
```

Add new token

```
 layout.friendly.url.page.not.found=/html/error/accessDenied.png
```

**Step 4**  Restart the server.

This solution will display error png in case of Error code 404 .

> Solution 2 :-

1. Go to `tomcat-7.0.27\webapps`
2. Go to each portlet and create new folder images if not available.
3. Paste attached accessDenied.png in images folder.
4. Go to WEB-INF of each portlet and edit web.xml .
               Add

   ```
      <error-page>
       <error-code>404</error-code>
       <location>/images/accessDenied.png</location>
   ```